# Add a column to DataFrame with value of 1 where prediction greater than a custom threshold

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to add a column to a `DataFrame` that should have the value 1 when the output class probability is high. Something like this:

```
val output = predictions
    .withColumn(
        "easy", 
        when( $"label" === $"prediction" && 
              $"probability" > 0.95, 1).otherwise(0)
    )
```

The problem is, `probability` is a `Vector`, and `0.95` is a `Double`, so the above doesn't work.  What I really need is more like `max($"probability") > 0.95` but of course that doesn't work either.

What is the right way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define UDF

```
val findP = udf((label: <type>, prediction: <type>, probability: <type> ) => {
if (label == prediction && vector.toArray.max > 0.95) 1 else 0
})
```

Use UDF in withCoulmn()

```
val output = predictions.withColumn("easy",findP($"lable",$"prediction",$"probability"))
```

Comment: This worked.  Thank You!  One thing I would add is that in order to make it work, I had to find the right type for probability.  It was a DenseVector.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35855382/converting-a-vector-column-in-a-dataframe-back-into-an-array-column

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example as to implement your question.
Create a udf and pass probability column and return 0 or 1 for the new added column. In a Row WrappedArray is used instead of Array, Vector.

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    (Vector(0.78, 0.98, 0.97), 1), (Vector(0.78, 0.96), 2), (Vector(0.78, 0.50), 3)
  )).toDF("probability", "id")


  data.withColumn("label", label($"probability")).show()

  def label = udf((prob: mutable.WrappedArray[Double]) => {
    if (prob.max >= 0.95) 1 else 0
  })
```

Output:

```
+------------------+---+-----+
|       probability| id|label|
+------------------+---+-----+
|[0.78, 0.98, 0.97]|  1|    1|
|      [0.78, 0.96]|  2|    1|
|       [0.78, 0.5]|  3|    0|
+------------------+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an udf, something like:

```
val func = (label: String, prediction: String, vector: Vector) => {
  if(label == prediction && vector.toArray.max > 0.95) 1 else 0
}
val output = predictions
  .select($"label", func($"label", $"prediction", $"probability").as("easy"))
```